# .netcore webapi debugging pause

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a web api project which is a console application and the main looks like

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Get the current settings.
    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out var minWorker, out var minIOC);

    // Change the minimum number of worker threads to four, but
    // keep the old setting for minimum asynchronous I/O 
    // completion threads.
    if (ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(250, minIOC))
    {
        Logger.Info("The minimum number of threads was set successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Error("The minimum number of threads was not changed");
        // The minimum number of threads was not changed.
    }

    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
}
```

When the debugger runs and paused it's always this line that is hit:

```
BuildWebHost(args).Run();
```

How do I make it pausing at the actual code being executed?

**Edit**
I'm pressing pause while some request is being executed and expect to see, for example, a call to the database when paused

Comment: Are you just pressing pause in Visual Studio or actually hitting a breakpoint?

Comment: pressing pause (hitting works fine by the way)

Comment: What do you expect pressing pause to do then? It's got to stop somewhere, and since `Run` doesn't return until you quite the app, that's where it shows.

Comment: But it's not the last entry in the call stack. is it? Why can't I see the whole call stack?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're not making much sense to me now. Like I already asked, what exactly do you expect to see in the call stack when you press pause?

Comment: I expect to see call to the database, for example

Comment: Why though? See my first comment. Let's say there are no requests happening to your app right now and you press pause, where do you think it will show you?

Comment: Ah I see why you ask now. No, I make the request through the browser and it takes a long time and while it's not finished I press pause.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't know you want to stop on that request. Pressing pause is almost never something you would normally do - use breakpoints.

Comment: It's what I do when I want to see which instruction takes longest. And it used to work fine with classic .net web api, but not in this setup....

Comment: Then your app needs more profiling/metrics/logging/etc.

Comment: If it pauses at that exact line, your app is doing nothing but "running". If something is actually happening, it will stop at the right line.

Comment: @Steven Lemmens No, I know for sure it's doing something (request isn't over yet) - most likely blocked in network call, but it never shows

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out see the answer

Comment: What @DavidG is saying is that the only thing that's *always* running is the web host, from that line where it stops when paused. You may know that you have an active request in progress, but there could be *many* active requests in progress. The debugger isn't going to just jump to some random request, it's going to stop at the entry point when paused.

Comment: Breakpoints don't have this issue because the debugger stops *within* the context of the request.

Comment: Yes, Chris explained that better than I did. Also, the reason it works differently in ASP.NET Core is because now we have control of the webhost, previously all that stuff was hidden inside IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging open threads window (Debug->Windows->Threads). Once paused one of those threads will be the right worker with required call stack.